# Hazelcast as Hibernate L2 Cache not working (0 hits, misses and puts)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I have set up a running Hazelcast Server Instance on my machine with the configuration:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcast_server">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="dev" password="dev" />
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="4031" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="true" />
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

On another JVM application, my hibernate configuration goes as:

```
<util:map id="hibernateConfig">
    <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="" />
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.check_nullability" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
    <entry key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.population" value="disabled" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="lucene\indexes" />
    <entry key="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT" />

    <!-- Enable L2 cache. -->
    <entry key="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    <entry key="generate_statistics" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="myApp"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.configuration_file_path" value = "hazelcast-config.xml"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client" value="true" />

</util:map>
```

And my cacheable entity is:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Simple {

@Id @GeneratedValue
int id;

String name;
```

And my Hazelcast Client Instance configuration goes as:

```
<group>
    <name>dev</name>
    <password>dev</password>
</group>

<instance-name>hazelcast_client</instance-name>

<network>
    <discovery-strategies>
        <discovery-strategy
            class="com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.multicast.MulticastDiscoveryStrategy"
            enabled="true">
            <properties>
                <property name="group">localhost</property>
                <property name="port">4031</property>
            </properties>
        </discovery-strategy>
    </discovery-strategies>
    <cluster-members>
        <address>localhost:4031</address>
    </cluster-members>
    <connection-attempt-limit>3</connection-attempt-limit>
    <socket-options>
        <reuse-address>true</reuse-address>
    </socket-options>
</network>
```

After persisting 2 entities to a locally hosted MySQL DB - ending transaction - fetching entities - ending transaction, I try to get statistics using:

```
for(String s :sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames())
        {
            System.out.println("[H-STATS] For region: \n"+ s + ":{"
                    + "\n\tHit count: "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(s).getHitCount()
                    + "\n\tMiss count: "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(s).getMissCount()
                    + "\n\tPut count: "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(s).getPutCount()
                    + "\n\tElement Count on disk: "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(s).getElementCountOnDisk()
                    + "\n\tElement Count in memory: "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(s).getElementCountInMemory()
                    + "\n\tSize in memory: "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(s).getSizeInMemory()
                    +"\n}");
        }
```

But what I get is:

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into Simple (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Simple (name, id) values (?, ?)
Jan 24, 2018 12:09:30 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select simple0_.id as id1_0_, simple0_.name as name2_0_ from Simple simple0_
[com.myapp.entities.Simple@1707ef71, ... com.myapp.entities.Simple@5bea4da2]
[H-STATS] For region:
myApp.com.myapp.entities.Simple:{
        Hit count: 0
        Miss count: 0
        Put count: 0
        Element Count on disk: -1
        Element Count in memory: 28
        Size in memory: 11924
}
```

Currently my primary aim is to check whether I have done my hazelcast configuration as a Hibernate L2 Cache Correctly. I feel like getting 0 hits, misses and puts means something is definitely wrong, so what am I missing?

**Edit**: FYI Maven imports in case of version mismatches:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate52 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate52</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.8.final

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the client configuration file is picked up by Hazelcast Hibernate plugin. Since you specified `hibernate.cache.hazelcast.configuration_file_path` as `hazelcast-config.xml` and you want to use the client in your Hibernate application, your **client** configuration file needs to be named `hazelcast-config.xml` and it needs to be in the root of your classpath.

You can also check if any data is stored in the cluster by having a simple client app, or you can use the entry browser feature of Hazelcast Management Center (which you can download over [here](https://hazelcast.org/download/)).

Another thing to watch out while dealing with Hibernate second level cache statistics, querying doesn't have any effect on cache statistics. Hits/misses are increased only on retrieval by ID. So if you mean executing a query when you say `fetching entities`, it is normal that the statistics for hits/misses are `0`.